# Query From Main Table When WHERE Clause Is In Detail Table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to query some data from Oracle DB, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I have two tables:

```
TableMain                              TableDetail

id    col1    col2 ...                 id     info
------------------------               ---------------
01    xxx     xxx                      01     AAA
02    yyy     yyy                      01     BBB
03    zzz     zzz                      02     AAA
04    iii     iii                      03     BBB
```

My goal is to select all rows from `TableMain` where it's `info` in `TableDetail` equal to a specific string specified by the user.

For example:

(1) If user specify `AAA`, it should return row `01` and `02` from `TableMain`

(2) If user specify `BBB`, it should return row `01` and `03` from `TableMain`

(3) If user specify nothing, it should return row `01`, `02`, `03`,and `04` from `TableMain`

I know that I can use the below for the `WHERE` clause to take care of example(3)

```
AND(:info IS NULL OR info = :info)
```

I tried using

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM TableDetail
    WHERE 1=1
          AND(:info IS NULL OR info = :info)) a,
    TableMain b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

But this will fail if there's no entry in `TableDetail` for the specific id.

For example: If the user specify nothing for `info`, this query will return row `01`, `02`,and `03`, which is missing `04` and it's not correct.

Please help me with this query, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `exists` clause:

```
select m.*
from tablemain m
where exists (select 1
              from tabledetail d
              where d.id = m.id and
                    d.info = :info
             ) or
      :info is null;
```

This moves the `null` comparison into the outer query to get all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
SELECT *
FROM TableMain main
WHERE (:info IS NULL OR EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableDetail detail
    WHERE main.id = detail.id
    AND detail.info = :info)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer works as well, but Gordon got it first. +1 from me.